# DateTime to DateTime2 conversion resulted in an out of range

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When i update my Datetime values , i want null ones that returned from my view to be considered as holidays but the problem is that they submitted to the database and this exception occurs so how to remove them when update my database ?

My code :

```
var wktimes = _context.WorkTimes.Where(wk => wk.OrganizationId == organizationInDb.Id).ToList();


for (int i = 1; i <= wktimes.Count; i++)
     {

         wktimes[i - 1].Day = Request.Form["Day_" + i.ToString()];
         wktimes[i - 1].From = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["From_" + 
       i.ToString()]);

         wktimes[i - 1].To = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["To_" + 
          i.ToString()]);

     //checking if the Day is holiday or not

   if (wktimes[i - 1].From.Year == 0001 && wktimes[i - 1].To.Year == 0001)
                {
                    holidays.Add(wktimes[i - 1].Day);
                    wktimes.Remove(wktimes[i-1]);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    continue;
                }

                wktimes[i - 1].OrganizationId = organizationInDb.Id;

                _context.SaveChanges();

            }
```

Comment: Which line throws exception?

Comment: _context.savechanges()

Comment: Wow! there are 2 such instances, your question is really not clear. You could use few more words to describe what values those variables hold when your problem occurs and how you want it to work.